# Create a "form" inside a sheet or transfer data permanently onto a new tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to find a way where for example I have sheet1 and sheet2:

Sheet 1 is where I write my data, lets say from A1:E10.

Is there a script that I can press or run after I am done inputting all the data for it to transfer it definitively onto sheet 2?

It has to be able to stay there regardless of what happens in Sheet1 after I submitted the data.

The other function I need is the data in Sheet1 can be longer (A1:E15) or sometimes less but it has to transfer and stay in sheet 2, every time below the last input.

I would like to avoid using Google Forms as it's quite basic and within the said A1:E15 I have formulas that calculate, so I can't really use Google Forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your input is in `input!A1:E` and your output is in `output!A:E`.

In the menu bar, select Script editor and type in the following script:

```js
function writeData () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var inSheet = ss.getSheetByName("input");
  var input = inSheet.getRange(1, 1, inSheet.getLastRow(), 5)
    .getValues;
  var outSheet = ss.getSheetByName("output");
  var outStartRow = outSheet.getLastRow() + 1;

  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < input[i].length; j++) {
      outSheet.getRange(outStartRow + i, j + 1)
        .setValue(input[i][j]);
    }
  }
}

function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var menuEntries = [];
  menuEntries.push({name: "Write data", functionName: "writeData"});
  ss.addMenu("Custom functions", menuEntries);
}
```

Save everything, refresh the spreadsheet. When you want to transfer the data permanently, just go to your menu bar, select Write data under the Customer functions menu.

Comment: I tried it but it does not seem to write anything only output sheet. I created a sheet called input and also a sheet called output, and put data from A1:E8 for testing, when I clicked the write data, nothing comes out on output